# Hide portion of element offscreen and push & reveal on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mobile

I'm building a responsive page that, when viewed on mobile, includes some popular behaviors.

I have an element that includes text and a link. The text portion needs to cover 100% of the width of the viewport and when clicked/tapped the link should push the text content left and reveal the link.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Flignats/0n0fwm20/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="block-one">
        I'm a bunch of informational text.
    </div>
    <div id="block-two">
        <a href="#">I'm a link!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#block-one {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #626366;
}
#block-two {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #969696;
}
    #block-two a {
        color: blue;
    }
```

How can I have block-one span the full width of the screen, block-two hidden off the screen, and, on click, animate (the margin?) block-two into view with block-one pushed to the left?

My apologies if I missed a clear example on site, most other questions were more complex.

I'd prefer not to build a jquery mobile page, though the push and reveal panels would accomplish this action. I'm also using Angular if nganimate is preferred over javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is pure css solution: http://jsfiddle.net/3wcfggmf/

I've used trick with `label` and `checkbox:checked` to recognize if element is clicked or not.

```
input:checked + #block-one {
  width: 75%;
}
```

If I didn't understand you correctly please let me know and I'll modify this PURE css solution for you :)

Comment: Very elegant solution! I understood OP's question differently, curious to see who got it right :)

Comment: I hope me :D I am squirrel reputatuion away :)

Comment: +1 for only using CSS! This was nearly what I was looking for, but your example helped me achieve what I needed. From your code, I kept the width @ 100% and transitions the margin-left: -25%.

Unfortunately, I couldn't use your exact example because I need to include multiple elements in the information area and nesting them within the label isn't the most elegant.

Instead, I fell back on jquery and updated my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Flignats/0n0fwm20/27/

Answer (score 0):

I forked your fiddle here with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/90gm224q/

Added CSS to yours:

```
#container * { transition: width .4s; }
#container.clicked #block-one { width:25%; }
#container.clicked #block-two { width:75%; }
```

The JS:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
    link = document.getElementById('block-two').getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

link.onclick = function() {
    container.className = 'clicked';
    return false;
}
```

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you can play with the CSS values for width to achieve your desired effect.

Comment: Nice job! Very close, I probably shouldn't have added a link because it was a little confusing. That link isn't needed to be a toggle, just get revealed.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this via **CSS transistions** and a **JavaScript class toggle**.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Leh5t9t6/

In my demo, clicking `#block-one` toggles a class which fires the CSS transision. I included a pure JavaScript and jQuery version in the demo (you mentioned you'd prefer not use jQuery).

I also edited the styles slightly to accommodate the off-screen link.

**Pure Javascript**

```
 var element = document.getElementById('block-one');
 element.addEventListener('click', function () {
   this.classList.toggle('reveal');
 }, false);
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#block-one').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('reveal');
});
```

Comment: Bingo! I went with a class toggle. Unfortunately, I saw your answer after Rafal Lesniak's, which helped me arrive to a solution more similar to yours.

Comment: @Flignats - No problem, if it looks like a good answer, an upvote would be appreciated ;)

Comment: I'll have to come back and upvote, I'm still under the required reputation amount :)